# Explicit heap dynamic variables

Tags: programming-languages

What are explicit heap dynamic variables and how does the binding property in them implemented? (not for a particular language I want to know about the overall functionality of these variables). I came to know that they are bound during run time what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit heap-dynamic variables are nameless memory cells that are
allocated and deallocated by explicit run-time instructions written by the programmer.
These variables, which are allocated from and deallocated to the heap,
can only be referenced through pointer or reference variables.